# Nested Modal in Shopware 6

Tags: bootstrap-modal, shopware, shopware6

In Shopware 6, I have a table in a modal window that serves as an order list. I'm attempting to implement a button that opens another modal on top of the main modal, fetches some information, and then saves or closes the nested modal and returns to the main modal. However, when I close the nested modal or click on another part of the screen, both modal windows close. How can I modify the close button to only close the nested modal and maintain the main modal window?

Answer (score 0):

Shopware 6.5 and forward uses modals of Bootstrap 5 and they [don't allow more than one instance of a modal at a time](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#how-it-works).

> Bootstrap only supports one modal window at a time. Nested modals aren’t supported as we believe them to be poor user experiences.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  It is really pity, that Boostrap 5 does not support nested Modal. I am still using Shopware 6.4.19.0. I think this version of shopware is using Boostrap 4. Does Bootstrap 4 support nested Modal?

Comment: I think I found the answer of my question in comments. Bootstrap 4 does not support nested Modal asw well.